# Парсинг данных с метеорологического сайта

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

Мне нужно спарсить данные [отсюда](http://old.meteoinfo.ru/forecasts5000/russia/republic-khakassia/abakan), в таблице представлены данные на несколько дней дней, если навестись, то будет подробная информация, такая информация доступна на каждый час, мне нужно спарсить все данные, которые есть на странице в этой таблице. Подскажите методы или идеи, пожалуйста

Comment: В чем заключается проблема? Если просто в поиске библиотеки и методов, то обращайтесь в интернет.

Comment: Парсить такой сайт - не самая хорошая идея. Во всяком случае, *beautiful soup* тут вряд ли обойдёшься. Почти наверняка, нужно будет использовать динамические средства типа *Selenium*. Однако, ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ подход заключается в том, что Вам надо связаться с администрацией сайта и запросить у них доступ к данным по API. Почти наверняка это будет за деньги, но тут уж ничего не поделаешь.

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужен парсер на python и библиотеки:

1. requests https://pypi.org/project/requests/
2. beautiful soup https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/

Дальше устанавливаешь их и пишешь парсер.